# Use emacs for batch-processing files

Tags: elisp, files, string

I'm a newbie elisp user. I would like to process a few hundred xml files and call an elisp function for each line which does an `query-replace` to fix a problem in these files.

My question is: how do I write the modified lines back to the file?

Subquestion: currently the lines are not changed to upper case - can you give me a hint why this does not work?

```el
(defun fix-xml-file (filePath)
  "Fix xml file"
    (with-temp-file **filePath**  <<-- Edit: the file path was missing here!
      (insert-file-contents filePath)
      ... do work here ... ) )

(defun fix-xml-folder (folderPath)
  "Fix all xml files in folder"
  (interactive "folder: ")
  (require 'find-lisp)
  (mapcar 'fix-xml-file (find-lisp-find-files folderPath "\\.xml$") ) )
```

Comment: @kaushalmodi how did you get the syntax highlighting to work?

Comment: Click on the `edit` button in your question and you'll see. ;-)

Comment: @Malabarba got it, compare does not work... <!-- language: lang-el -->

Comment: @Beginner Yes, you'll need to hit edit on the question and then edit on the last revision to see that. The diff hides the html comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`with-temp-file` writes `buffer` to `FILE`.  So on it's own it should do the trick.  However it requires `FILE` to be passed as an argument before `BODY` so that it knows what file to write.  Based on your code above, the following should upcase the entire file.

```lisp
(defun fix-xml-file (filepath)
  (with-temp-file filepath
    (insert-file-contents filepath)
    (upcase-region (point-min)
                   (point-max))))
```

For other purposes, replace `(upcase-region ...)` with an appropriate modification.

For a regex-replace you will probably want something similar to:

```
(unless (eobp)
  (re-search-forward "string to change" (point-max) 'noerror)
  (replace-match "replace with this"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are two apporaches one uses only emacs, and the other also uses shell.

In both cases it is usefull to separate the problem in two:

1. write a defun which process a single file
2. get the list of files and apply the defun to each file

Also I wouldn't insert the file contents in the temp buffer. I would open the file, process it, and the save it -- so that I only need file name once.

## A. Using Lisp only

### A.1. defun which process a single file

```lisp
(defun my-process-file (fpath)
  "process the file at fullpath FPATH ..."
  (let (mybuffer)
    (setq mybuffer (find-file fpath))

    (goto-char (point-min)) ;; in case buffer is open
    (while (search-forward-regexp "REGEXP" nil t)
      (replace-match "SUBSTITUTION" nil t)) ;; if you need to reference things like (string-match 1) use: t nil

    (save-buffer)
    (kill-buffer mybuffer)))
```

### A.2. process files

Do:

```lisp
(require 'find-lisp)
(mapc 'my-process-file (find-lisp-find-files "/path/to/dir/" "\\.xml$"))
```

## B. Using shell + elisp

### B.1. script which process a single file

Make the following shell script `my-process-file.bash`:

```lisp
#! /bin/sh
":"; exec emacs --no-site-file --script "$0" -- "$@" # -*- mode:emacs-lisp -*-

;; emacs options:
(setq make-backup-files nil)
(setq next-line-add-newlines nil)

;; open file:
(find-file (nth 1 argv))

;; process file:
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (search-forward-regexp "REGEXP" nil t)
  (replace-match "SUBSTITUTION" nil t)) ;; if you need to reference things like (string-match 1) use: t nil

;; save file:
(save-buffer)
```

(do not alter first two lines)

### B.2. command to process files

Apply it to xml files:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.xml" | parallel my-process-file.bash {}
```

Comment: The shell scripting tip is nice! Can you explain what the parts of the line beginning with ":"; exec emacs does?

Comment: @Beginner: first two lines send the whole script to emacs. The start of the second line: `":";` makes the most of the second line a comment in emacs (and the whole second line is a valid elisp), while still keeping the line a valid shell expression. As far as I remember that is an explanation that was given where I picked the trick up.